# Mounting an Apple Tv on ubuntu?

Tags: mount, apple, input-devices

***Note:*** *I wasn't sure whether to put this question here, or on [Apple.SE](https://apple.stackexchange.com/), so **If** you think it would be better served there, feel free to migrate it, Although I thought that because it was primarily about the mounting of the drive on Ubuntu, it was more appropriate to ask here.*

---

I recently bought an apple tv. I wanted to see what exactly was inside, So I tried mounting it as a device in ubuntu. When I did it, there were 2 devices that were listed: "Apple Tv", and "Documents on Apple Tv"

The "Apple Tv" drive worked fine, but when I tried opening "Documents on apple tv", I got the following error message:

```
Error: unhandled lockdown error (-256)
```

why is this happening? What do I have to do to get it to mount properly?

Answer (score 1):

May be the problem is that apple tv uses IOS 5, in this case you have to install the lib to could mount the tv.

I could try installing the next lib:

```
sudo apt-get install ifuse libimobiledevice-utils
```

then try this comand:

```
idevicepair unpair && idevicepair pair
```

now try again!